# Is it possible to open outlook client calender using java script?

Tags: calendar, outlook

Is it possible to open outlook client calender using java script? Like how we are opening outlook mail window using `mailto`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can automate Outlook from JavaScript. See [Compose and Send E-mail from JavaScript by using Outlook Automation 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajnishkaushik/archive/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007.aspx) for a sample code.

Comment: Now i am able to open the appointment using  below code                     `try {
            var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
            var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(1);
//            theMailItem.to = "asd";
//            theMailItem.Subject = ("asd");
//            theMailItem.Body = ("asdas");
            theMailItem.display();
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        } `       . Is it possible to open the calendar like this ?

Comment: You can use the `GetDefaultFolder` of the `Namespace` or `Store` class to get the calendar folder.